# unable to create IOS Distribution Cirtificates itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

I m trying to create Distribution certificate but there is disable icone appers in itunes so how can i create distribution and developement cirtificates?

Screen shots is  [image]

Comment: I think one is already created for that account.

Comment: yes but i  want to create for another app , distribution cirtificate..

Comment: is there any limits for creating cirtificates???

Comment: I think yes, it depends upon the type of account. But lets wait for others opinion.

Comment: type of account means???

Comment: Individual, Company/Organisation etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129617/discussion-between-prince-and-mr-bista).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reached to the limit of maximum number of **"Ad Hoc Distribution Certificates".**

As per I know the limit of certificate is 3. If you want to create new certificate, you must have to revoke old certificate.

if you want to distribute the different app, Then you have to **create different provisioning profile not certificate.**